# Accessing a div element in an array of li elements

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to access a div in an li array

```
<ul>
<li class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
 <div class="news-item">
</li>
<li class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
<li class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
 <div class="news-item">
  <div class="image">
  <div class="details with-image">
    <h2>
    <p class="standfirst">The best two-seat </p>
  <div class="meta">
    <div class="pub-date">26 April 2012</div>
    <div class="topic-bar clearfix">
       <div class="topic car_review">review</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

I am trying to access the "div class="topic car_review">car review "and get its text.
The reason I am specifically using that text is that, depending on what the text is it would enter specific steps.

Code that I am using is

```
@topic = @browser.li(:class => /views-row-#{x}/).div(:class,'news-item').div(:class,'details').div(:class,'meta').div(:class,/topic /).text
```

The script was working fine before and suddenly it has stopped working and is just not able to get the div(:class,'news-item').

The error message I get is

```
unable to locate element, using {:class=>"news-item", :tag_name=>"div"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
```

I tried div(:class => /news-/) but still its just not able to find that element

I am really stuck!!!

Comment: 1) Can you give us a link to the page you are testing? That can make helping you a lot easier.  
2) Don't use a long chain of objects to find what you want unless that is the only way to differentiate it from similar objects on the page.  If divs with the class "topic car-review" are not found elsewhere on the page, just cut down to using that (as Justin shows in his answer)
3) if things that were working are now broken and you didn't make any change, you may need to have a really close look at the page HTML, as likely the issue is a change there, to names or using frames or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that when you are doing `li(:class => /views-row-#{x}/)`, the x means you are iterating over all rows? If so, then your script will fail on the `row-2` since it does not contain the `news-item` div (resulting in the error that you see).

If there is only one of these 'topic car_review' div tags, you can just do:

```
@topic = @browser.div(:class, 'topic car_review')
```

**Update** - Iterating over each LI:

If you need to iterate over each LI, then you could do:

```
@browser.lis.each do |li|
    @topic = li.div(:class, 'topic car_review').text
end
```

Comment: All the li elements have news-items. Its just that i have pasted details of only 1 li element.

Comment: I added how I would iterate over the LIs. If that doesn't work then I would suggest you update the question with a full HTML sample and your code that reproduces the problem. Other than by making the assumptions already listed, I have not been able to reproduce your problem.