# Accessing the attribute of a div element in an array of div elements

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, watir

in the answer to this question [Accessing a div element in an array of li elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397787/accessing-a-div-element-in-an-array-of-li-elements?rq=1)
and when i look here http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Collections+of+HTML+Elements

I dont see or don't understand what i need to do

what i am trying to do is make a spreadsheet with my guilds player_name, player_id and player_lvl.

this is the page that has the guild members.                                              [guild page](http://game.ageofchampions.com/aoc/?cmd%5B0%5D=112&guild_id=138668) 
her is some sample of the html

```
<div class="guild_board">

<div class="item_box_guild" data-playerid="1256824509">
   <a onclick="doCmd(81,{'player_id':'1256824509'})"><div class="tile_50">
 <div class="avatar_container_50">
 <div class="avatar_image" style="background-image:url(//assets.ageofchampions.com/avatar/09/45/82/56/12/avatar_1351896996145.png);">
 </div>
</div>
 <div class="over">
   <img src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/187582_1256824509_1172546357_q.jpg">
 </div>
<div class="lock"></div>
 </div>
</a>
 <div class="content">
  <div class="stat" style="width:225px;">
    <a onclick="doCmd(81,{'player_id':'1256824509'})">~|SR|~ Kariselle</a> |
        Level 348 <hr>
          Battle Score: 23,951,169
```

this code works to get the first member and i could do (=>index (2)) to get the next member and so on. at the momunt we only have 10 members but it could get alot bigger. and if i dont have to I dont want to have to write this for each member.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'google_drive'
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'http://game.ageofchampions.com/aoc/?cmd%5B0%5D=112&guild_id=138668'
b.text_field(:id => 'email').set 'email'
b.text_field(:id => 'pass').set 'psswd'
b.button(:name => 'login').click
session = GoogleDrive.login('username', 'pass')
ws=session.spreadsheet_by_key('spreadsheethe').worksheets[0]
b.goto 'game.ageofchampions.com/aoc/?cmd%5B0%5D=112&guild_id=138668'
#b.divs(:class => 'item_box_guild').each do |div|
playerid_1 = b.div(:class => 'item_box_guild').attribute_value(:'data-playerid')
#playerid_1a = puts attribute_value(:'data-playerid')
#end
playername_1 = b.div(:class => 'item_box_guild').div(:class => 'stat').a.text
#playerlvl_1 = b.div(:class => 'item_box_guild').div(:class => 'stat').text
#layerlvl_1a = playerlvl_1\s+id="0"\s+value="(.+?)"
# Gets content of A2 cell.
p ws[2, 1]  #==> "hoge"

# Changes content of cells.
# Changes are not sent to the server until you call ws.save().
ws[1, 1] = "PLAYER ID"
ws[1, 2] = "CHAMPIONS NAME"
ws[1, 3] = "LEVEL"
ws[2, 1] = playerid_1
ws[2, 2] = playername_1
ws[2, 3] = "still working on lvl"
ws[3, 1] = "does this"
ws[3, 2] = "still"
ws[3, 3] = "work"

ws.save()

# Dumps all cells.
for row in 1..ws.num_rows
for col in 1..ws.num_cols
p ws[row, col]
end
end

# Yet another way to do so.
#p ws.rows  #==> [["fuga", ""], ["foo", "bar]]

# Reloads the worksheet to get changes by other clients.
ws.reload()
```

Comment: What's your question exactly? Do you need help creating a spreadsheet or parsing HTML for multiple members? If it is the latter, can you provide an HTML snippet that has multiple members?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you need Watir? [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) is often easier and faster for scraping, unless javascript execution is required.

Comment: to answer your second question first. there is no reason, I do not know enough about the diff library. two answer your first question. I am looking for something like 'playerid_1 = b.divs(:class => 'item_box_guild').attribute_value(:'data-playerid').each do |div|' with the expected out come of player id of each player in list form. so that i can post it to the spreadsheet in cell A,2 and it will fill down.

Comment: yes i can provide as much of the html as you would like. I will post some more now

Comment: here is a link to a file with more code [https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PouPLvLaKAH0AMMA2sj0UL8cTx8EWPYNKjFJOlSwe4w/edit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get a collection of the players when you do:

```
b.divs(:class => 'item_box_guild')
```

When you iterate over each with:

```
b.divs(:class => 'item_box_guild').each do |div|
```

The variable `div` will be a div in the collection. Inside the iteration, you want to refer to `div` rather than `b.div(:class => 'item_box_guild')` to get each player.

Try doing this:

```
b.divs(:class => 'item_box_guild').each do |plaher_div|
  playerid = player_div.attribute_value(:'data-playerid')
  puts playerid
  #=> This will be 'player1' during the first iteration, 'player2' during the second, etc.
end
```